# how can i migrate jquery to javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hello everybody here I'm working on Angular.js and I wanted to resize a div dynamically when I resize the browser. I founded this gentleman's code http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/SfJ8c/ on the JSFiddle, I pick it up and changed it. I don't want to use any jQuery code.

I tried to migrate it like this.

```
myApp.directive('resize', function ($window) {
  return function (scope, element) {
    var w = $window;

    scope.getWindowDimensions = function () {
      return {
        'h': w.innerHeight
      };
    };
    scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimensions, function (newValue, oldValue) {
      scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;

      scope.style = function () {
        return {
          'height': (newValue.h - 245) + 'px',
        };
      };

    }, true);

    w.bind('resize', function () {
      scope.$apply();
    });
  }
})
```

It fires when the page is reloaded, and the div change the height but it's w w.bind is not a function. Can someone please help me to migrate it?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+add+event+listener+in+javascript

Comment: You could probably do this with CSS alone.

Answer (score -1):

I think following code block should be work

```
var jquery = document.createElement('script');
jquery.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js';
jquery.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jquery);
```

Comment: Okay, i got it, you can add it to your js file